# Reading data fields from a loaded dylib in another process

Tags: c, macos, mono, dynamic-linking, mach-o

I am writing an app that tries to read some data from another process's memory. This other process is loading a libmono.0.dylib where the target data (assemblies) should reside.

With some mach-o based code I can iterate the loaded dylibs of the target process and get the mach header baseaddress of the lib above. From here I can get to the symbol table that gives me the address of the function that returns the struct with the relevant data:

[image: _mono_get_root_domain symbol]

In the mono source code it looks like

```
MonoDomain* mono_get_root_domain (void) { return mono_root_domain; }
```

Is my assumption correct that the address of 0x18a934 holds the returned struct? If yes, is this address relative to the dylib header (=header_addr+addr) or I also need to add some slide, or just use it as it is?
Does the same hold for every other address I encounter when I follow this address?

Answer (score 0):

> I am writing an app that tries to read some data from another process's memory

Each process has its own virtual memory space and is protected by the kernel. Whist the dylib may be shared, if a function is returning an address, it will be in the virtual memory map (VMMap) of the process that called the function.

In order to map a target process's memory address to your own process address space, you need the target's task port. You used to be able to call `task_for_pid` to obtain a process's task from its pid, but since OS X 10.10 (El Capitan) and the introduction of System Integrity Protection (SIP), this is no longer possible.

If the data resides within a loaded dylib, just load the dylib into your own process with [dlopen](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and get the address of the function with a call to [dlsym](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dlsym.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/dlsym).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I already got that part, I have the loaded header address and the pointer to the symbol. As you can see above I found a pointer "inside" the disassembled code, now how do I use it? If i read dylib_base_address + pointer then I get just random stuff. What vm region is it pointing to?